Transform a c[][person][name] en JSON in curl -data
I tried during long time to transform parameter cc[][person][id] in data in curl on unix
curl --globoff -X POST --insecure 'http://host/api/sendMail' -H 'Content-Type: applicationjson' -d ' { "subject":"tititi","person":"19858", "cc":[ "person" : [ "id":"13205" ] ]}'  -H 'Authorization: key 1:MMMEKOEES'

It fails, I don't know:

how to put, (escape ou simple quote?) double quote " in "cc":[ "person" : [ "id":"13205" ]
how to multi array transform in json [ or ```{``

I succeed to understand it beginning by "cc":  because this request
curl --globoff -X POST --insecure 'http://host/api/v2/sendMail' -H 'Content-Type: applicationjson' -d ' { "subject":"tititi","person":"17813", "cc":[["person"]]}'  -H 'Authorization: key 1:MMMEKOEES' 

"message": "This value should not be blank."
"message": "Unexpected field names: "0"" ```


i tried -d ' { "subject":"tititi","person":"17813", "cc[][person][name]":[ [ false ] ]  }' error "Unexpected field names: "cc[][person][name]""

the parameter multi array cc[][person][id] is a a parameter to be used

-H 'Content-Type: applicationjson should be -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
